# Matlab Stepwise Logistic population growth simulation

Tags: matlab, while-loop, population

I am trying to make a Matlab simulation of logistic growth, with a population of trees, T, and a maximum number of trees, M. However, unless I use a growth factor, k of 1, the numbers that return are very strange.

**The vector result of T. There are no such thing as negative trees. I don't know how I got negative infinity trees.**

```
Columns 1 through 11

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -1.0504      -Inf

  Columns 12 through 22

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 23 through 33

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 34 through 44

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 45 through 55

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 56 through 66

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 67 through 77

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 78 through 88

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Columns 89 through 99

      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf      -Inf

  Column 100

      -Inf
```

**The code:**

```
t= 1:1:100;
i=1;

k=0.25;
M=100;
T(1)=1;

while i<100
    T(i+1)=T(i)+k.*T(i).*(M-T(i));
    i=i+1;
end

disp(T)

plot(t,T);
```